# MySQL QUERY in preparing for too long

Tags: mysql

The following SQL has a preparing time of 30+ second. Is the SQL which is wrong, or the fact that I have close to one million result in the database? Can this SQL be optimized not to have it in preparing for that long?

```
UPDATE url_source_wp SET hash="ASDF2"
WHERE (url_source_wp.id NOT IN (
   SELECT url_done_wp.url_source_wp FROM url_done_wp WHERE url_done_wp.url_group = 4)
)
AND (hash IS NULL) LIMIT 50
```

Comment: prepare or execution time ?

Comment: do you have an index on the url_group column?

Comment: State: preparing
Execution time is just a couple of ms longer. Preparing is 98% from execution time.

Answer (score 0):

If preparation is your issue, you can pre compile it to a stored procedure.

See this :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could more optimally do this update across a JOIN, avoiding the use of the sub-select.

```
UPDATE
  url_source_wp AS s
  INNER JOIN url_done_wp AS d
    ON s.id = d.url_source_wp
SET
  s.hash = 'ASDF2'
WHERE
  s.hash IS NULL
  AND d.url_group = 4
```

You need to make sure you have indexes on `s.id`, `d.url_source_wp`, `s.hash`, and `d.url_group`.  Also, note that you can't use `LIMIT` with multi-table syntax, so if this is important this suggestion will likely not work for you.

Comment: @user2296949 I guess you can't use LIMIT on multi-table. I will adjust my answer